# How do I deal with 3 categorical IVs, one continuous IV and 4 ordinal DVs?

Tags: statistics, spss

So, I am writing up a paper for a study I conducted, and I am finding the statistics to be more difficult than I thought. Essentially, I have:

1. three categorical independent variables, each of which are binary
2. one categorical variable which is out of 4 points, and
3. four ordinal DVs, each of which have three levels.

Ideally, what I would want is to be able to run an ANOVA of some sort, but the data do not meet parametric assumptions. I do not know of any tests which would allow me to test all of my IVs and DVs in a single model (the assumptions for linearity, normality, and parametric data are not met). Ideally, I'd also like to run a test where multiple comparisons wouldn't be an issue.
I know that is a lot, so please forgive the long windedness of the question!
Thank you so much for all your help!

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow! Please note that questions about statistics are off topic here (we answer programming questions) - you should post your question [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)

Comment: I think you misunderstood the model assumptions, have a look at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6350/anova-assumption-normality-normal-distribution-of-residuals.